# How to interpret tensorflowjs predict results

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to expose my image categorising model to my github pages.

In python, after running `model.predict`, I used to receive the probability of the given image. On tensorflowjs, I receive a tensor and I have no idea how to interpret that data:

Js code:

```js
  img1.onload = function() { 
    const imageTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img1);  
    const smalImg = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imageTensor, [150, 150]);
    const resized = tf.cast(smalImg, 'float32');
    const t4d = tf.tensor4d(Array.from(resized.dataSync()),[1,150,150,3])

    //const preprocessedInput = imageTensor.expandDims();
      
    const prediction = model.predict(t4d);
    predicted.innerHTML = prediction.shape;
    console.log(prediction);
  }
```

output:

```json
t {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(2), dtype: "float32", size: 1, …}
dataId: {}
dtype: "float32"
id: 48
isDisposed: (...)
isDisposedInternal: false
kept: false
rank: (...)
rankType: "2"
scopeId: 9
shape: (2) [1, 1]
size: 1
strides: [1]
__proto__: Object
```

Here is my github page: https://ramonmedeiros.github.io/cat_dog_classifier/
Here is my model: https://github.com/ramonmedeiros/cat_dog_classifier/blob/main/hello.py

Answer (score 0):

`prediction` is a `tensor` object. So if you want to get the values of the tensor, `prediction.dataSync()` or its async counterpart `prediction.data()` can be used